# Real usage of “pure” quaternions in stereometry?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quaternions, solid-geometry, hypercomplex-numbers

There are two major categories of the "quaternions".
It is well-known that a (nonzero) versor represents a [three-dimensional rotation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Quaternions). A versor is a unit quaternion or a normalized quaternion: $$a+b{\bf i}+c{\bf j}+d{\bf k}\text{ with }a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1^2\text{, where }a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R\text.$$ It is also known that (the vector part of) a vector quaternion or a pure quaternion describes a spatial location, where a vector quaternion is a quaternion that has vanishing scalar component (see, e.g., [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Using_quaternions_as_rotations&:%7E:text=Euclidean%20vector) and [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Quaternions_and_three-dimensional_geometry&:%7E:text=coordinate%20vector)).

The former has proved useful in many places; nonetheless, I cannot find any application (other than rotation operations in 3 dimensions) for the latter (namely, a quaternion of the form $0+b{\bf i}+c{\bf j}+d{\bf k}$). Of note, the latter itself is a (special class of) quaternion rather that the location of a 3D point – just like although a complex number corresponds to a 2D point, a complex number itself is neither coordinates of that point nor a ${\rm2}$-dimensional vector.  Whilst I notice that complex numbers are useful in fielding certain intimidating problems (including, but not limited to, olympiad-level ones) in planar geometry (*not* complex geometry), I wonder if there exists some case where the so-called vector quaternions can be used to address **non-trivial** problems in solid geometry.
For instance, now that Ptolemy's classical theorem may be derived by [elucidating the four points as *complex numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem#Proof_using_complex_numbers), and it has been generalized to ${\rm3}$-dimensional Euclidean space (see below), can vector quaternions be utilized for showing the following 3D versions?

1. For any four (distinct) points $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ in $\mathbb R^\color{red}3$, they are either concyclic or collinear iff $$\begin{vmatrix}0&{\left\lvert AB\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert AC\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert AD\right\rvert}^2\\{\left\lvert BA\right\rvert}^2&0&{\left\lvert BC\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert BD\right\rvert}^2\\{\left\lvert CA\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert CB\right\rvert}^2&0&{\left\lvert CD\right\rvert}^2\\{\left\lvert DA\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert DB\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert DC\right\rvert}^2&0\end{vmatrix}=0\text.$$
2. For five arbitrary points $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and $E$ in $\mathbb R^\color{red}3$, they lie on a sphere of (in)finite radius iff $$\begin{vmatrix}0&{\left\lvert AB\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert AC\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert AD\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert AE\right\rvert}^2\\{\left\lvert BA\right\rvert}^2&0&{\left\lvert BC\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert BD\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert BE\right\rvert}^2\\{\left\lvert CA\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert CB\right\rvert}^2&0&{\left\lvert CD\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert CE\right\rvert}^2\\{\left\lvert DA\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert DB\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert DC\right\rvert}^2&0&{\left\lvert DE\right\rvert}^2\\{\left\lvert EA\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert EB\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert EC\right\rvert}^2&{\left\lvert ED\right\rvert}^2&0\end{vmatrix}=0\text{. }$$

A proof using (elementary) linear algebra for the first generalization can be found [here](https://web.math.sinica.edu.tw/mathmedia/HTMLarticle18.jsp?mID=46408#:%7E:text=%E5%AE%9A%E7%90%863%20), and the second one was proved by [Arthur Cayley](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511703676.002) in 1841. Notwithstanding, neither of these proofs makes use of the alleged vector quaternions. Inasmuch as complex numbers are instrumental in the classic proof the original Ptolemy's theorem, is it possible to prove the two aforementioned three-dimensional analogues using vector quaternions?

Edit. Complex numbers can doubly serve as rotation operators as well as position vectors, and so can quaternions. What I am looking forward to is: In view of the fact that when we use complex numbers, the context does not need to be rotation operations, and we may simply use complex numbers to undertake geometrical analysis in a coordinate-free manner (for example, proving [Ptolemy's theorem](https://moscow.sci-hub.st/2319/5d4740aa683a8f403e39309eaf4dfeb2/andreescu2014.pdf#page=241) without "synthetic" axiomatic methods or explicit coordinate-based method), which often has nothing to do with the algebra of rotations for the plane, can't we do the same thing for “pure” quaternions in stereometry?

Comment: _I cannot find any application for the latter (namely, a quaternion of the form 0+++)_. Huh? Unless you're going about composing rotations without ever actually applying them, you'd _have_ to express the input position $x$ in that form to compute $qxq^{-1}$ for a unit quaternion $q$ to see what the output position is.

Comment: You seem to be drawing a false analogy. If complex numbers a points in 2D space, then analogously general *quaternions* are points in 4D space. Why would you expect vector quaternions (pure imaginary) to have a similar role to complex numbers (real+imaginary)?

Comment: (2) can almost certainly be expressed using [conformal geometric algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_geometric_algebra). (1) probably can as well but isn't as clear to me. I don't think you can do anything using *only* vector quaternions.

Comment: @rschwieb I think that you may misunderstand my words: "The former" means the unit quaternion, and "the latter" means the vector/pure quaternion. If I understand right, what we use in 3D rotation is actually the unit quaternion (the former) rather than the vector quaternion (the latter). (At least the Wikipedia article mentions that “a quaternion representation of rotation is written as a versor (normalized quaternion)”.)

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff The Wikipedia articles [Using quaternions as rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Using_quaternions_as_rotations) (the third paragraph) and [Quaternions and three-dimensional geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Quaternions_and_three-dimensional_geometry) (the first paragraph) appear to suggest that a vector quaternion (not a unit quaternion) does denote a three-dimensional point. So it seems that such analogy is still reasonable?

Comment: Vector quaternions form a 3-dimensional vector space. You can use any 3-dimensional vector space to represent spatial points; it's an entirely uninteresting fact. What matters is that you are using the algebra product. Vector quaternions represent spatial points insofar as *you use them to apply rotation quaternions*, as rschwieb said. In their notation, $x$ **is a vector quaternion**; this is how you actually rotate points with quaternions.

Comment: Now, if we want to draw an analogy between complex numbers and quaternions, **you cannot deny that the real part of a complex number plays a special role in the algebra product**. If it plays such a special role, then a good analogy between complex numbers and quaternions should preserve this.

Comment: @user688486 In my comment,  $q$  is _the former_ and the $x$ you're applying it to is _the latter_.  If there is some misunderstanding, it is not what you're describing.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Oh, I see where vector quaternions are used in 3D rotations, yet I believe I'm looking for something else. We know that in general, a complex number can represent not only a two-dimensional rotation operator (after normalization) but a coordinatized point (or a position vector) as well. The point is: when a complex number is treated as a planar point, it's not just useful for dealing with 2D rotations. [To be continued.]

Comment: @rschwieb [Cont.] One may find that in the above proof of Ptolemy's theorem, the use of complex numbers is _wholly irrelevant_ to 2D rotations (even if using complex numbers to represent planar points is ***also*** an **entirely uninteresting** fact). But so for as I know, each *practical* use of vector quaternions (which denote spatial points) is related to 3D rotations (Did I miss something?), and I can't find any other use unrelated to rotations in three dimensions. (Labour the point: The use of complex numbers can be connected with and can also be unconnected with 2D rotation operations.)

Comment: @user688486 I don't know what you're talking about.  The situation is simply: you have things representing rotations and things representing the things rotated. Quaternions are used for the _former_ and the vector quaternions represent the _latter_.  They go hand-in-glove with each other, and it's hard to see what you'd do if one was missing.

Comment: @rschwieb Well, in short, my main problem is: why can't we use (a special class of) quaternions in a context other than 3D rotations (just like we can use complex numbers in a context other than 2D rotations)? We know that complex numbers are often useable in plane geometry problems that do not contain 2D rotations, so it is natural to find the potential use of (a special class of) quaternions in solid geometry problems that do not involve 3D rotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder if there exists some case where the so-called vector quaternions can be used to address non-trivial problems in solid geometry.

If you consider representation of rotations as addressing a non-trivial problem in solid geometry, then I think the following counts as well.

The subset of unit length quaternions that have real part zero can be used as reflections in a way that is almost like how the unit-length quaternions are used for rotations.

In detail, if $n$ is a unit-length quaternion with real part $0$, it defines a reflection $x\mapsto nxn$, and $n$ is the normal vector to the plane of reflection. ($x$ is, again, from the subspace of $\mathbb H$ representing 3-space.)

Another related answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2256664/29335

In truth there are a plethora of applications of reals, complexes, quaternions, and their "dual-" and "split-" varieties (I am reluctant to follow tradition and refer to all these as 'hypercomplex numbers' but unfortunately that is what we are saddled with) for various applications, for instance [homogeneous transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_quaternion#Dual_quaternions_and_4%C3%974_homogeneous_transforms) and [screw theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory#Homography), it's just that they are a bit more obscure.

Books that talk about applications of Clifford algebras also explain how to do projective geometry and conformal geometry and other things with higher dimensional analogues of $\mathbb H$.  There are really a *ton* of applications out there.